# How to access current request from bootstrap?

Tags: request, kohana-3, bootstrapping

Is it possible to access the current request in Kohana's bootstrap? I tried accessing `Request::$current` but `$current` doesn't seem to be defined at that stage. Is there any way around that? Also at what point in the application is `Request::$current` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it after Kohana initialization.

> Kohana::init(...);

Also, good practice is using interface methods instead of public variable. I'm wondering why the developers keep $current as a public field.

So.. use

> Request::current();

Also, It seems that using

> Request::initial();

is better idea. But it depends on your realization.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible, because `Request` object is created in *index.php* after including bootstrap.php:

```
// Bootstrap the application
require APPPATH.'bootstrap'.EXT;

/**
 * Execute the main request. A source of the URI can be passed, eg: $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'].
 * If no source is specified, the URI will be automatically detected.
 */
$request = Request::factory();
```

If you must access it, do it in the *index.php* after it has been created, although maybe you could tell us what exactly are you trying to do?